# Adding one byte to a hexadecimal number

Tags: c, binary, boolean, hex

I seem to have confused myself so much that this doesn't make sense anymore.

1 byte = 8 bits.

So if I have a memory location such as

```
0xdeadbeef
3735928559 (base10)
1101 1110 1010 1101 1011 1110 1110 1111
```

Now if I add **one byte** to `0xdeadbeef`, what is the binary sequence I'm adding? Is it `1000`? If I add 1 bit, I get `0xdeadbee0`, and if I add 1 bit 8 times, I get `0xdeadbef7`. Which is correct?

I remember from microprocessors the counter incremented in PC += 4, which gives `0xdeadbef3`, so I'm not sure which is the right answer.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense... asking what you get if you add "one byte" is like asking what you get if you add "one digit" to a decimal number... it depends what digit it is!

Comment: @MatteoItalia Sorry, I'm referring to memory locations. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Ok, so if that address is a memory location (measured in bytes) if you move forward of one byte, the number is incremented by one.

Comment: I think you have some major confusion here.

Comment: @HotLicks: that's the only thing that is really clear :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I understand from your question is that, you are confused with adding a bit and a byte to the counter.
Since memory addresses are measured in bytes (in programming languages), any arithmetic operation to it is done in bytes.
To increment counter, adding `1` to it is like increment it to one byte next to the base address. Adding `1` to `0xdeadbeef` will increment it to `0xdeadbef0`.

Comment: Correct. If I add 1 byte or 1 bit, I still end up at `0xdeadbef0`, which I have confused myself due to the fact that 1 byte equals 8 bits. I think the proper term is 1 byte represents 8 bits rather than equals?

Comment: Yes. You are right. A bit is `0` or `1`. A byte is any sequence between `0000 0000` to `1111 1111`. So, `1`-byte represented by `8`-bits.

Comment: "Since memory addresses are measured in bytes (in programming languages), any arithmetic operation to it is done in bytes." careful, in C operations on pointers are performed in units of the base type of the pointer.

Comment: It depends. `int *ptr` is measured in `int`, so if you do `ptr++` the underlying memory address is incremented by `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia; I know. That's why I use general term "bytes" rather than "a byte".

Answer (score 2):

> I'm referring to memory locations.

So 0xdeadbeef is an address. If you increment it by 1 byte, you simply add 1 to it.
i.e. `0xdeadbeef + 1 = 0xdeadbef0`

**Concluding** It looks like adding 1 bit to the address increments pointer by 1 byte because you access memory at byte granularity and increment memory in terms of number of bytes. But actually you added number 1 (i.e. 0x00000001). In case you want to increment by 4 byte, you add 4 to the address because memory is addressed(unit of) as number of bytes.

Comment: OP used deadbeef though, not that it really matters

Comment: Yes and I used his example to `add 1 byte` in his terms. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

what is adding one byte? byte needs to have value .
you need to add **number** to a number , not size (8 bits) to number...

If the byte you are adding = 0x08 --> 1000 in binary , and
0xdeadbeef+ 0x08 = 0xdeadbef7

Answer (score 1):

If, as I gathered, that thing is a memory address, which is measured in "number of bytes after the base (zero) address", if you move one byte forward in memory the memory address is incremented by one.

Think of it like this: if you measure the distance from the start of the road in meters, if you move forward of one meter (which is your unit of measurement) the distance from the start increases of 1.

Be careful though that pointers in C (and C++) work in a slightly confusing (at first) way: if your pointer is of type `T *`, each arithmetic operation on if is performed in units of `T`, so the underlying memory address is moved around in steps of `sizeof(T)`.

For example, if you have:

```
int a[2];
int *ptr=a;
int *ptr2=ptr+1;
printf("Delta in ints: %d", (int)(ptr2-ptr));  // will print 1
char *cptr=(char *)ptr;
char *cptr2=(char *)ptr2;
printf("Delta in chars: %d", (int)(cptr2-cptr)); // will print sizeof(int), typically 4
```

Answer (score 0):

In computers each memory location holds 8-bit(1-byte) of data. So, when we add 1 byte it will simply add 1 byte to the memory location.

Answer (score 0):

when you add 1 to an address of word-size, 1 is interpreted as a word-size string of bits that has a decimal value of 1.

For your case, `0xdeadbeef` has 32-bits or 4 bytes. So adding 1 is like doing `0xdeadbeef + 0x00000001`. Adding 300 is like `0xdeadbeef + 0x0000012C`

Just in case you're wondering if you can add more than word-size to the address, it's not possible, because the address can't be bigger or smaller than the word size.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be confusion between byte representation and binary equivalent of a number

A byte is represented by 8 bits, so 1 byte in binary form would be represented as `0000 0001` and not that 1 byte is formed by adding up 1, 8 times successively, that would be 8 bytes.

Bytes are usually represented in decimal system and memory addresses are represented in hexadecimal. You can only add one hexadecimal number to another hexadecimal number.

0 to 9 bytes in decimal would be equivalent to 0x00 to 0x09 bytes in hexadecimal system, so adding anything between 0 to 9 bytes to an address would be direct addition. If the bytes you are adding are greater than 9, you'd have to convert them to hexadecimal and add to move to that address.

So adding one byte to `0xdeadbeef` would simply result in,
`0xdeadbeef + 1 = 0xdeadbef0` or as an example adding 64 bytes (`0x40 bytes`) to `0xdeadbeef` would be `0xdeadbeef + 0x40 = 0xdeadbf2f`